# Vault login by AWS IAM getting VaultException with X-Vault-AWS-IAM-Server-ID header validation failed

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

Vault Login by AWS IAM getting below exception.

```
com.bettercloud.vault.VaultException: Vault responded with HTTP status code: 400
Response body:

{     "errors": [         "error validating X-Vault-AWS-IAM-Server-ID header: expected \"dev.vault-shared.com\" but got \"vault-dev.yourcompany.io\"" ] }



    at com.bettercloud.vault.api.Auth.loginByAwsIam(Auth.java:892)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of Vault server- Client configured with `iam_server_id_header_value` as `dev.vault-shared.com`

So server side expecting `dev.vault-shared.com` but client is sending `vault-dev.yourcompany.io`

> **Solution**

Set `iam_server_id_header_value` value as this `vault-dev.yourcompany.io` rather than `dev.vault-shared.com`

Check the existing value of `iam_server_id_header_value` by calling below curl request from your Vault server.

```
    curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/aws/config/client
```

Response

```
{
  "data": {
    "access_key": "ADBCDIAJBRHKH6EVTXDHA",
    "endpoint": "",
    "iam_endpoint": "",
    "sts_endpoint": "",
    "sts_region": "",
    "iam_server_id_header_value": "vault-dev.yourcompany.io"
  }
}
```

If `iam_server_id_header_value` value is `vault-dev.yourcompany.io` then client configuration is ok

**Reference**

https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/auth/aws#configure-client

**Note:**
This error occurs only when you change your vault server CNAME from **dev.vault-shared.com** to **vault-dev.yourcompany.io** and not changed Vault server client configuration.